# Simplification of groovy substring call with null argument

Tags: if-statement, groovy, substring, simplify

I'm using some archaic version control, and am trying to parse the comments using Groovy for Jenkins usage.

I managed to get the Groovy code working, but was wondering if there might be a way to simplify the code.

The test string which I use is as follows:

```
text = "IL!21234 12/3/18 3:46 PM user_d Some comments with new\nlines interspersed and pointers to commits\n(IL!1234)\nIL!1234 1/2/17 2:46 AM user_x Some other commit\n"
```

The expected result is:

```
tasks = ["IL!21234 12/3/18 3:46 PM user_d Some comments with new lines interspersed and pointers to commits (IL!1234)", "IL!1234 1/2/17 2:46 AM user_x Some other commit"]
```

Here follows my code:

```
m = (text =~ /IL!\d+ \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M [a-z_]* .*/)
matchStarts = []
tasks = []

while(m.find()) {
  matchStarts << m.start()
}

matchStarts.eachWithIndex { matchStart, index ->
  if (matchStarts[index + 1]) {
    tasks << text.substring(matchStart, matchStarts[index + 1]).replace("\n", " ").trim()
  } else {
    tasks << text.substring(matchStart).replace("\n", " ").trim()
  }
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there would be a nicer way to deal with the if/else.

Thanks,

Comment: hi, you may try something like task = text.replaceAll("\n"," ").replace(")",");").tokenize(";"). it depends if you can cope without double quotes or not ...

Comment: That resembles the previous solution I had. The problem is it's not robust enough.
I have no way to know what the last character of the task string is. The one I gave is only an example.
So I have to first find all the start of match, after which I can take substrings from the start of one to the start of the next one.

As I'm trying not to repeat myself, I was wondering whether I could call `tasks << text.substring(matchStart).replace("\n", " ").trim()` and have as the second argument to substring some value that would be correct no matter if this is the last task or not.